# Where is this magnetic rail gun getting its energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, conservation-laws, perpetual-motion

Please watch this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9myr32FgCWQ&t=9s) of a magnetic rail gun moving a marble.

So as you already know, Conservation of Energy states that "energy can be neither created nor destroyed, but can only change form". Where is this rail gun getting the energy to move the marble? It looks like it's being created out of thin air. Is it not possible to create a perpetual motion machine by modifying this rail gun? For example, what if a funnel and tube was added that can catch the moving marble, which feeds the marble back to the rail gun to continue the loop? I'm not 100% sure, but I can't imagine any kind of friction will cause this loop to stop.

Thanks!

Comment: As @Dale explained, there is no paradox here when it comes to conservation of energy. However, as a student, I had it drummed into me that “magnetic fields do no work,” to which this seems to be a counter example. But microscopically, it is actually internal electric forces that cause the macroscopic acceleration of the projectile, not magnetic ones.

Comment: This comment is in response to the edits specifying how you'd make a perpetual motion machine.  The steel ball always stops inside the field, so cannot be routed back to the start.  The projectile that it hits is not ferromagnetic, so while it could be routed to the starting location, it would not work as a replacement for the steel ball.

Comment: I would like to see an explanation of how the line of magnets accelerates the steel ball.

Comment: @R.W.Bird the steel ball is attracted toward the magnets. When the ball is at one end of the line, the force is toward the middle. The acceleration all occurs near the end (or, in the cases where there’s a progression to more powerful magnets, near those transitions).

Comment: Any time you think a phenomenon offers a route to unlimited free energy, it's time to re-think your understanding of the phenomenon or the route.  Energy is always conserved.  So, you're right to ask the question, but don't assume that you've found a simple loophole in the laws of physics; instead assume that your understanding is not yet complete.

Answer (score 2):

> Where is this rail gun getting the energy to move the marble?

The energy comes from the work required to move it from its final location back to the starting location. It is no different than rolling a marble down a hill. You get energy out of rolling it down, but as soon as you try to roll it back up you use all of that energy. You cannot incorporate this into a perpetual motion machine, which has to be restored to its original state.

Also, additional marbles do not change this. Assuming that the marbles are identical then the absolute best that you can do is transfer the first marble’s kinetic energy entirely to the second marble, in which case you are in the same situation as the paragraph above. Assuming instead that the marbles are not identical, then you could get a second (lighter or less magnetic) marble to the top from the energy of the first marble, but that second marble would be unable to get the first marble back up.

Both electromagnetism and gravity conserve energy in this scenario, so there is no clever way around it. You can get energy from this once, but not perpetually. To restore the system to its original state always requires energy. In particular, it requires the person’s hand to do work by pulling the marble away from the final location.

Comment: `The energy comes from the work required to move it from its final location back to the starting location.` - Could a second marble be added to hit and move the first marble from the final location back to the starting location? I don't think a lot of energy would be needed to move a second marble to the starting location, which causes the first marble to move at a significant speed. I get the analogy you're trying to make but it feels like the kinetic energy that is being released is more than what is being put in (ie: the energy to move the marble at the starting location). Thanks!

Comment: @burnt1ce Whenever you're unable to find an error in reasoning that suggests a violation of conservation of energy, it's useful to refer to https://xkcd.com/2217/, to which the mouseover text is along the lines of "well, there's one right here at the bottom".

Comment: @Ben51 I'm not surprised by your type of response, but I also don't blame you. Thanks for the laugh

Comment: @burnt1ce I have added a paragraph addressing the multi-marble scenario. It adds complication but does not change the outcome

Answer (score 0):

A permanent magnet will attract a ferromagnetic object. But when you apply force to remove the object from the magnetic field you will find that there is no net energy gain.

Answer (score 0):

There is no deviation from the laws of physics. Magnetic potential energy is the another source of energy apart from gravitational potential energy. As long as magnetic property of the metal exists it will last

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/361084)